# How i take hex input into array from users c

Tags: c, arrays, string

I will take hex input from user into `buffer` array, but i don't take it, `scanf` does not appropriate. Input data like this (0x 06 41 42 43 0f 52 53). Also then i want to  transform string to integer type some part of array. I used `atoi`, what is best way for it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char buffer[1000];
    char dest[3];
    int x;

    //scanf("%s",buffer);
    x=atoi(strncpy(dest,buffer+1,4))
}
```

Comment: You could save it as a string and then parse it. And convert it to decimal.

Comment: `(00 06 41 42 43 0f 52 53)` are octals (not hex)

Comment: @KeineLust octals does not include f.

Comment: @OğuzhanAvcı Hex have `0x` as a prefix. Any thing that doesn't is not hex.

Comment: @OğuzhanAvcı  `06` is an octal, use `0x06` or `0x6` or simply `x6`

Comment: @KeineLust okey, i edit 00 to 0x

Comment: [sample code](http://ideone.com/AOYpJD)

Comment: @OğuzhanAvcı you can keep `00` it is not actually a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following simple function converts a string with a hexadecimal number to an integer:

```
int atox(const char *s)
{
    int x= 0;
    while (*s) {
        x= x*16+(*s>'9'?(toupper(*s)-'A'+10):*s-'0');
        s++;
    }
    return x;
}
```

and call it like:

```
printf("%02x\n",atox("42"));
printf("%02x\n",atox("a1"));
printf("%02x\n",atox("A1"));
```

Note that the string must be exactly the string to convert, so no spaces or whatever.

Comment: Thanks, i understand your function, but it give Segmentation fault (core dumped) why?

Comment: See update: probably you call with an improper string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code using `strtol` function considering numbers as Hex inside the string (For `base` value `8` they will be octal):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *s="00 06 41 42 43 0f 52 53";
    char *endpoint=s;
    int base=16,count=1;
    long int result=0;

    do
    {
      result=strtol(endpoint,&endpoint,base);
      printf("value %d %ld\n",count,result);
      count++;
    }while((endpoint - s) < (size_t)strlen(s) );
    return 0;
}
```